# Detach node child process after receiving a first message

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a system with node.js where the user is able to spawn worker processes from a web interface, and I'm having trouble combining these two criteria for the system:

1. The web server process and the worker process should run independently, so that if the web server crashes, the worker process isn't affected.
2. The mother process should be able to receive at least one initial message from the worker process. After that message, I want to log the output from the worker process to a file.

I've been able to accomplish both criteria by themselves, but not together. Here's what the relevant parts of my code currently looks like:

```
function spawnWorker (id, callback) {
    var worker = spawn("node", [require.resolve("worker"), id], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "pipe"]
    });

    worker.unref();

    var logfile = fs.createWriteStream("foo.log");

    worker.stdout.once("data", function (data) {
        worker.stdout.pipe(logfile);
        worker.stderr.pipe(logfile);

        callback(undefined, data.toString());
    });
}
```

This meets criteria 2 (ie. it receives the first message from the worker and redirects all following output to a file), but if I kill the mother process, the worker process is killed as well, even though the output has been redirected.

My guess is that this is because the worker's stdout and stderr are piped to the mother process before they're sent to the file stream. If I were to pass in a stream when spawning the process, according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio), node would instead duplicate that stream in the worker process:

> The stream's underlying file descriptor is duplicated in the child process[...]

Is there a way I can remove the connection between the mother process and the worker process after having received the first message? Or should I use some type of RPC to accomplish this, and if so, what would be a good choice for this one message once communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using node's [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module to spawn a server on a random port that is passed to the worker when it's started (so it knows where to send a response when it's ready).

Here's an example of an implementation of my solution, to clarify, this meets the requirements of:

1. saving the log output of the worker process,
2. keeping the worker process detached from the mother process (so that if the latter crashes, it doesn't affect the worker)

`server.js`

```
var net = require("net"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
    randomPort = require("get-port");

randomPort(function (port) {
    var server = net.createServer(function (connection) {
        connection.on("data", function (data) {
            server.close();
            /**
             * Response received from worker, this is where you would put
             * your logic that returns a response to the client that initiated
             * the request to the server.
             */
        });
    });

    server.listen(port);

    var logfile = fs.createWriteStream("log");
    var worker = spawn("node", ["worker.js", port], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: ["ignore", logfile, logfile]
    });

    worker.unref();

    worker.on("close", function (status, message) {
        console.log("worker closed", status, message);
    });
});
```

`worker.js`

```
var net = require("net");

var options = process.argv.slice(2),
    rpcPort = Number(options[1]);

var client = net.connect({port: rpcPort}, function () {
    client.end(JSON.stringify({started: true}}));
});
```