# Electron close Browserwindow but not child process

Tags: node.js, electron

Hello im working with Electron and i want on a button click that windows media player open and my electron app close.

My problem is that all windows will be close. Is it possible only close Electron App and not Windows Media Player?

```js
// My Method 
var child = require('child_process').execFile;

clickButtonVar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    child(dynamicPathForPanoExe, function(err, data) {
        
        if(err){
           console.error(err);
           return;
        }     
    });
    ipcRenderer.send('close-me')
    
});

// And in main JS

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      //devTools: false
    },

   fullscreen: true,
   enableLargerThanScreen: true
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('close-me', (evt, arg) => {
  
  app.exit()
})
```

Thanks for your help!!! :)

Comment: can you use `spawn` instead of `execFile` and pass the `detached: true` option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep forked child process alive in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945246/how-to-keep-forked-child-process-alive-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks @pushkin, that was the soloution :) :)